# How to get a network configuration overview in Powershell?

Tags: networking, powershell

On Linux machines I used to get most of the network info I need from ifconfig and ip route commands.

In PowerShell I am still confused how to get a quick overview of machine's network configuration. Either I'm missing somethings or this information is really scattered across several (by default not conveniently formatted) commands.

On my own PC I ended with these functions, but I often work on other machines where it's not available, while sometimes these machines also not connected to Internet so installing various nugets is not an option.

So what would you recommend for getting network info on clean PowerShell 5?

```
function ifconfigAlias {
    Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | Select-Object `
    @{ name = "Idx"; expr = { $_.NetAdapter.InterfaceIndex } },
    InterfaceAlias,
    @{ name = "Address"; expr = {$_.IPv4Address}; }, 
    @{ name = "MAC"; expr = { $_.NetAdapter.LinkLayerAddress } },
    @{ name = "Link"; expr = { $_.NetAdapter.Status -replace "Disconnected", "Down" } },
    @{ name = "Speed"; expr = { $_.NetAdapter.LinkSpeed } },
    @{ name = "Forwarding"; expr = { $_.NetIPv4Interface.Forwarding } },
    InterfaceDescription `
    | Sort-Object InterfaceAlias | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
}
Set-Alias -Name my-ipconfig -Value ifconfigAlias

function routePrintAlias {
    param(
        [Parameter(HelpMessage="Sort order")]
        [ValidateSet("iface", "dest")]
        [string]$SortBy = "dest"
    )

    $Lut = @{"if" = "InterfaceIndex"; "dest" = "DestinationPrefix"}
    $SortProp = $Lut[$SortBy]

    Get-NetRoute | `
        Sort-Object $SortProp | `
        Where-Object { `
            ($_.AddressFamily -eq 'ipv4') -and `
            ($_.DestinationPrefix -ne '255.255.255.255/32') -and `
            ($_.DestinationPrefix -ne '224.0.0.0/4') } | `
        Select-Object `
            DestinationPrefix, `
            NextHop, `
            @{name = "Idx"; expr = { $_.InterfaceIndex } }, `
            InterfaceAlias, `
            RouteMetric | `
    Format-Table    
}
Set-Alias -Name my-route -Value routePrintAlias
```

Comment: You can just run `ipconfig` or `ipconfig /all` in PowerShell or you could use `Get-NetIPAddress` or something like `Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select-Object -Property IPv4Address`

Comment: Even `GIP` works

Comment: So there are still no simple Powershell tool which shows NIC+MAC+IP address?

Comment: No language/product/solution that has ever been released to the world is 100% of everything you can ever want out of the box. It can't be. They are only capable of getting you about 80% (that's the norm), and the other 20% (that stuff unique to you or others) is up to you through custom code/efforts. This is why custom modules, extensions, etc., exists.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to edit this to your liking

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | 
Select-Object -Property @{
    Name = 'IPAddress'
    Expression = {($PSItem.IPAddress[0])}
},MacAddress | 
Where IPAddress -NE $null
```